# Are "planning on visiting" and "planning to visit" interchangeable?

Tags: grammar

More specifically, are "planning on visiting" and "planning to visit" interchangeable in the following sentence:

"I was planning on visiting you during your office hours next week but there was no list to sign up on outside your door."

If only one of the two options works, why?

Comment: There are lots of posts here about "to" (infinitive) versus "-ing" (gerund). Please go through related previous posts. Good Luck.

Comment: In that context, they are interchangeable. In general, _plan on_ + `Gerund` means the same as _plan_ + `Infinitive`; I can't think of a context where they're different.